Why are files showing a lock icon in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer?"
I've noticed that some of the files in my Visual Studio solution are showing a lock icon in the Solution Explorer window. When I hover over the lock icon with my mouse, it says "checked out." What does this lock icon mean and why are these files locked? How can I unlock them so I can make changes?
I'm working on a project in Visual Studio and I'm seeing some files in the Solution Explorer with a lock icon next to them. When I hover over the lock icon, it says "checked out." I'm not sure why these files are locked or what "checked out" means in this context. I need to edit these files, but I'm not sure how to unlock them. Can someone please explain what's happening and how I can resolve this issue?

It means you are using   version control.
It is not an issue.
Once you edit the file, the lock icon will be replaced with a red mark.

Your visual studio is connected to the repository where code is stored.
To do the changes in the files you need to check out the files from source branch.

checked out means you are currently working on that particular file and locked for others so, any other user should not modify the same file in the same repo at that time.
It helps to avoid the merge conflicts.

Also make sure not making changes directly to main branch .
